# Graph in tikz: Edge-Orthogonal Label Positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I'm using tikz to plot Graphs, each edge shall have an edge-label. This edge label should be next to the **center** of the edge.

I put an `edge node` at every edge. There should be a small **orthogonal** distance from the label to the edge's center. So starting from the edge's center, go a specified distance along the orthogonal direction of the edge and put the label there.

Till now I got that which does not work fine.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,BCOR=4mm,DIV=12,]{scrartcl}

  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.75]  
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,draw,fill=white}]
      \node (5) at (0.5,4.5) {1};
      \node (6) at (3.5,4.5) {3};
      \node (7) at (1.5,6) {3};
      \node (8) at (4.5,6) {1};
    \end{scope}      
    \begin{scope}[>=latex,
                    every node/.style={midway},
                   every edge/.style={draw=black,thick}]
      \path [-] (5) edge[right] node {\footnotesize $1$} (6);
      \path [-] (6) edge[right] node {\footnotesize $1$} (7);
      \path [-] (6) edge[right] node {\footnotesize $1$} (8);
  \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `quotes` library instead of `edge nodes`? Then you can specify the edge node within the edge itself by `edge["1"]`. The position of the edge node is then controlled by the key `auto` which can take `left` or `right`.

The meaning of `left` and `right` to the `auto` key is that the node will be placed on the left of the path respecting ist direction (e.g. with `auto=left` if the path is going from the left `(0,0)` to right `(1,0)` the node will be placed on the path midway and above).

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.75]  
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,draw,fill=white}]
      \node (5) at (0.5,4.5) {1};
      \node (6) at (3.5,4.5) {3};
      \node (7) at (1.5,6) {3};
      \node (8) at (4.5,6) {1};
    \end{scope}      
    \begin{scope}[
        >=latex,
        every node/.style={font=\footnotesize},
        every edge/.style={auto=right, draw=black,thick}]
      \path [-] (6) edge["1"] (5);
      \path [-] (6) edge["1"] (7);
      \path [-] (6) edge["1"] (8);
  \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: definitions `>=latex` and `[-]` are surplus :)

Comment: I know... I struggled with leaving it or taking it out, but I thought maybe the OP minimized the example and in the actual drawing it's needed. So I left it there to facilitate copy-pasting, though I really do not like it... `:P`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to nice answer of *Guilherme Zanotelli* (with less consideration of OP MWE):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, inner sep=1pt, font=\footnotesize},
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style = {circle,draw}]
      \node (5) at (0.5,4.5)    {1};
      \node (6) at (3.5,4.5)    {3};
      \node (7) at (1.5,6)      {3};
      \node (8) at (4.5,6)      {1};
    \end{scope}
\draw[thick]    (5) to ["$1$"] (6)
                (7) to ["$1$"] (6)
                (6) to ["$1$"] (8);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 mostly for openly disregarding the OP's MWE! `;D`